# making a get request and getting xml string in ionic app

Tags: xml, angular, http, ionic2

I am using the link above to get data using HTTP get method and extracting the body using body.json()

the returned data in string format but i need it to be array to be able to deal with it

hint : data in xml format on the server

Comment: this is the link i am using to get the data  http://www.health-always.com/api/AdApi/GetDepartments/

Answer (score 0):

take out

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"> and </string>
```

using regex or however you like. then do JSON.parse the rest.